# T-SQL to return the row when one column value changes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table with say 10 columns and for example, and I want to extract the row where the value of one column changes, for example if the data value in column 3 changes, and I want to get that row and all subsequent rows when the value in col. 3 next changes.

How is the best way to achieve this?

I've tried similar refs, but not quite there.

TIA

Comment: You can achieve this by use of [Triggers] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) for that Table

Comment: your question is not clear. Please show your table schema, sample data and expected result. Please avoid posting image. Use formatted text

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea (not specifically to Column No 3, but you can edit and implement it as per your need)

**Step 1: At Insert / Update:** Save checksum per row of the row data. Example of 5 fields (including first field being nullable and second being integer)

```
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
    v = BINARY_CHECKSUM (
        ISNULL(c1, ''),
        ISNULL(c2, 0),
        c3,
        c4,
        c5)
) c_sum
```

Now save this `c_sum` into a field for the row in your table.

**Step 2: AT Select:** Select where checksum has changed:

First, recalculate the c_sum as above and lets call the previously saved value as `c_sum_current_value`

Then match new against old to get only the updated rows:

```
SELECT
bla, bla
.

FROM bla
.
.
.
WHERE 
c_sum_current_value!=c_sum
```